# How to list installed python interpretators?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

How to list installed python interpretators?

For example `which python` give me only the current python interpretator, but I need all of them.

If it matters I using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can you try this: `sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'` ([source](http://askubuntu.com/a/505449))

Answer (score 1):

`ls -la /usr/bin/python*` should show you all of your python executables.

Comment: Assuming you have actually intsalled them in that path